# Is there any practical way to partially absorb the heat from a refrigeration condenser

Tags: heat-transfer, refrigeration

I have currently been experimenting with a phase change material to absorb the heat given off by the condenser in a small refrigeration system (about 1/5 hp compressor) and while it does absorb a substantial amount, it often requires a huge volume of the phase change material (many many kilograms of the stuff) which is not practical due to the heat.

Is there any other alternatives that can absorb heat without a huge increase in weight?

Comment: Can you explain the purpose of the heat capture? What are you trying to do?

Answer (score 1):

Many systems are designed to avoid condensors and matched to feed directly into other systems.

One example is refrigeration units that pre-heat water on its way to a boiler - any temperature rise is less work the boiler has to do.

You need to consider what systems you can feed heat into and how “direct” you can achieve that - the more conversions the poorer the efficiency....